# Ideas in how to attack the Union-Closed sets conjecture

Tags: combinatorics

The conjecture is formulated as

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a non-empty family of finite  sets closed under union. Prove that exists a element $x$ with the following property $| \{ A \in \mathcal{F};  x \in A \} | \ge \frac{|\mathcal{F}|}{2}$.

It's obviously true for the case where the set has a single element and after a few sets with more elements become clear that is a combinatorial problem. Does the problem changes if we take families of closed intervals?

Comment: Found that this was a "challenge", given its an open problem.

Comment: The conjecture is historically formulated for finite sets. Did you intentionally omit that assumption? By closed intervals, do you mean closed intervals of reals? And what exactly do you mean by "does the problem change"? Obviously it does change, in that it's then a different problem; in what way are you thinking it might change?

Comment: You have to formulate the conjecture just a bit more carefully, so that $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset\}$ isn't a counterexample. If the union-closed (finite) family $\mathcal F$ consists of intervals, then $\bigcap\mathcal F\ne\emptyset$. But I think you meant to ask, what happens if each member of $\mathcal F$ is a union of closed intervals? Good question. I don't know if that's an easy case or if it's as hard as the general problem. But then I'm not an expert on the union-closed sets conjecture.

Comment: @joriki No. I just forgot.

Comment: Also known as “Peter Frankl’s problem”

Comment: @ArturoMagidin indeed.

Comment: There's no need to demand that the family is non-empty, since for an empty family any object is contained in half (namely zero) of the sets. Instead, you need to exclude the case $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset\}$, as explained by @bof above. Also, the conjecture is usually formulated for finite families of finite sets; if you didn't intend to allow infinite families of finite sets, there's another "finite" missing.